# Single SignOn - Best practice

Tags: authentication, architecture

I need to build a scalable single sign-on mechanism for multiple sites. Scenario:

- Central web application to register/manage account (Server in Europe)
- Several web applications that need to authenticate against my user database (Servers in US/Europe/Pacific region)

I am using MySQL as database backend. The options I came up with are either replicating the user database across all servers (data security?) or allowing the servers to directly connect to my MySQL instance by explicitly allowing connections from their IPs in my.cnf (high load? single point of failure?).

What would be the best way to provide a scalable and low-latency single sign-on for all web applications? In terms of data security would it be a good idea to replicate the user database across all web applications?

**Note:** All web applications provide an API which users can use to embed widgets into their own websites. These widgets work through a token auth mechanism which will again need to authenticate against my user database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not integrate the authentication on the database level, as in replicating the db or allowing access from the other servers. This might become hard to maintain. I would prefer a loosely coupled approach by exposing a simple service on your central server that lets the other app servers run authentication requests.

You should look into the following issues (probably more):

- How to avoid cleartext transmission of passwords between servers
- You probably can't throttle the service if a network of application servers authenticates all their users from the same IP, so you might want to restrict access to certain clients to avoid rogue machines mass-probing for valid accounts.
- How to centrally enforce things such as session expiration
- How to handle / avoid service downtime

Techniques that might be helpful:

- [Cryptographic CRAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge-response_authentication#Cryptographic_techniques) (to avoid password transmission)
- [Certificates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_certificates) (to prove the clients' identity)

Alternatively, you might want to have the clients use the central service to obtain a token that is then promoted to and verified by the target server. There's architectures that work similarly (e. g. [Kerberos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29) ticket servers) which may serve as inspiration.

Comment: Great and useful input

Answer (score 0):

You should go for Oauth2 or SAML.